# how comes this mean recurrect time

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have this transition matrix:

$$P=\begin{pmatrix} 0.9 & 0.1 \\ 0.4 & 0.6 \end{pmatrix}$$

I need to find the stationary distribution. I know two formulas for this:

1. $\pi = (\pi_1,\pi_2) = (\dfrac{p_{21}}{p_{12}+p_{21}},\dfrac{p_{12}}{p_{12}+p_{21}})$ where $p$ is position in the matrix
2. $\pi = 1(I-P+U)^{-1}$

i took the first and got the stochastic row vector $(0.8, 0.2)$ which is the stationary distribution. but later in the textbook, they mentioned that the mean recurrent time for this are $m_1 = 5/4$ and $m_2 = 5$. how do these recurrent times come? I know the formula for recuurent time and i somehow dont get it right.. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isn't $m_1=5/4=10/8=1/0.8$ and $m_2=5=10/2=1/0.2$ so time $m_i$ or frequency $1/m_i$.

Comment: And this is even a theorem: $E_i(T_i)=1/\pi_i$.

Comment: @Did, thank you for comment. this made the whole thing clear. I learnt the recurrent time as  sum of $n*f_{ii}^n$, but now i know that the mean recurrent time is just $\frac{1}{stationary \quad  distribution}$. thanks a lot

Comment: @doniyor You are welcome. If I may, try to read as much from [Norris' Markov chains](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/) as you can.

Comment: @Did, yeah i will. thanks